# Handle SimpleXMLElement error if bad url given

Tags: php, simplexml

I am getting some products via some xml files daily.

Sometimes there are 4 files, sometimes there are up to 10.

I want to process them in a loop with SimpleXMLElement from an URL.

Here is what I try:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    try {
        $SimpleXML = new \MFF_System\SimpleXMLExtended($file, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

But unluckily I've got warning:

> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): http://example.com/file_6.xml:42:
>   parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes:
>   0xE1 0x6D 0x6F 0x67

In this case, there were only 5 files, so when I try to get the 6th, that gaves me the main page from the site. I've also tried with to surpress the warning without success.

```
 $SimpleXML = @new \MFF_System\SimpleXMLExtended($file, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
```

Is there any way to handle these errors in order to avoid them stopping my script?

**EDIT**

I can not use `file_get_contents` because in this case, I am getting memory limit error, and I can not increase the memory. These are so big files, one of it is 1GB. Guess what, the developer of these files are put the product images binaries into the file :((((((((( (I can not speak with him).

**EDIT2**

In php documentation [(here)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) I've read `$var = @new some_class();` should work.

If I am using:

```
$SimpleXML = @new \MFF_System\SimpleXMLExtended($file, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
```

I get this:

> Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in ........\Parser.php on line 19

I thought, yeah, it is much more better, because this is an `Expection`. If I wrap with `try/catch`, I just get the same error.

```
try {
    $SimpleXML = @new \MFF_System\SimpleXMLExtended($file, LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Exception');
}
```

`\MFF_System\SimpleXMLExtended` is just extends the `SimpleXMLElement` class, and use a method to add `CDATA`, nothing special.

Comment: Standard (unrelated) tip: `LIBXML_NOCDATA` is almost certainly not doing what you think it does. Everyone thinks "SimpleXML has a problem with CDATA" because they trust the unhelpful output of `var_dump` rather than the correct output of `echo` or `(string)$node`. (Apologies if you're using it for the actual correct purpose, of converting CDATA nodes in the *output* (`->asXML()`).

Comment: More relevantly, have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php and related functions?

Comment: Since SimpleXML will only handle well formed XML, have you tried to load a DOMDocument from the resource as HTML and XPATH to the elements you need? (I assume you don't need the binaries included in this resource).

Comment: @IMSoP yes I've tried. Tried to add the internal error, it does not helped. Tried every solution what I found at here SO, nothings helped.

Comment: @code-kobold It's a well formed XML, since, my collegue produce me this, and he sucked with a lot of hexa codes. So he wrote bash script with sed, what is fixed the XML, so he can read it through `simplexml_load_file()` if I surpres the error with `@`.. In this case, the variable will false. But not with `SimpleXMLElement`